# に+しよう and って欲しい in requesting

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference between:

> 俺に行こう
> 俺に行って欲しい

They both mean "you want me to go". When should I use each of them?

Comment: Both sentences are ungrammatical (the latter may appear as part of a sentence, though).

Comment: Your assumption is kind of incorrect. With this current question it is a bit hard to provide a good answer. Maybe if you add some resources to why you think those sentences mean what you think they mean. Or maybe editing it to something like "How to make a request in Japanese" and then provide a couple examples of what you wanna say, and what parts you are having trouble with.

Comment: Or did you hear them used in that sense/context somewhere?